# Toggling a taxi between busy and available states

Tags: ruby

Is there a better way to do this? That `switch_status` method seems like it could be made a lot more compact.

```
class Taxi
  def initialize
    @status = :available
  end  

  def switch_status
    if @status == :available
      @status = :busy
    else
      @status = :available
    end
  end
end

t = Taxi.new
t.switch_status
```

Comment: I'm on the fence about this. It does look like overly simplified pseudocode, so understand why it was put on hold. On the other hand, the method in question is technically ok to review. On the third hand, simply shortening the method is trivial (cf ternary). On the fourth hand, shortening it may not be relevant as the context calls for a different solution altogether, but there's no context present in the question. On the fifth hand, I have apparently grown three new hands, and should probably see a doctor.

Comment: If it helps - I pulled it out of an API I'm writing that's not quite functional yet. I didn't want to post the full class because I thought the other broken pieces would be too distracting.

Comment: @newUserNameHere, Quote: "the other broken pieces", those would render a question on that code off-topic. Code presented for code review should be working code, it doesn't need to be optimal but it does need to do what you intended for it to do.

Comment: @newUserNameHere I'd recommend finishing the API, then presenting it all at once for review, rather than in bits and pieces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I voted to reopen, though I still don't consider this a good CodeReview question. Perhaps my answer here will shed some light on why I think that.

You say you want to shorten the `switch_status` method. Well, Ruby has ternaries, same as many other languages so:

```
def switch_status
  @status = (@status == :available ? :busy : :available)
end
```

And done. Shorter.

But the reason this question feels incomplete is because that, in and of itself, is completely equivalent to the original code. So it's not really a review, just a demonstration of an alternative `if..else` syntax found in many languages.

A *review* would require knowing more about why this method exists. What its purpose is, when you need it, why it's using symbols, and so on.

To start, just having the `switch_state` method is odd. You presumably have to know what state the taxi (as the class name suggests it is) is already in, in order to see if switching it makes sense. But your code contains no mechanism for determining the current state. In fact, the only way to get a `Taxi` instance to return something is to *change* its state. Calling `switch_state` will return the new state, and you'll have to work backwards from there or switch it back again.

E.g. suppose you have an instance, and want to know its state. Currently, you'd have to do this:

```
some_taxi.switch_state # flip it once
current_state = some_taxi.switch_state # flip it back again
```

That makes very little sense.

Also: You're switching between exactly two states - which is what booleans do already. So why aren't you using booleans? They're limited to two states, so you're certain it's either one or the other (whereas a symbol can be anything). So you could just as well do this:

```
def switch_status
  @busy = !@busy
end
```

Really, that should do the same trick, since this taxi has only two states.

And also, given the lack of context, I'd say you're entire class could, in effect, be replaced with just a boolean, since the class's only purpose right now is to store a boolean state. So cut out the middleman. A raw boolean value would even tell you its current state, which is more than your class does now.

But presumably you want the encapsulation and the symbols for something. Or do you want symbols? A more Ruby'esque way to inquire about a known set of states would be with `?`-methods:

```
def busy?
  @busy
end

def available?
  !@busy
end
```

Or you can just have one of 'em and negate their value, e.g. `!taxi.busy?`. Either way, it's infinitely better than flipping the state twice just to find out what it currently is.

If you *still* want symbols, write an accessor:

```
def status
  @busy ? :busy : :available
end
```

Then again, if this is a taxi, does it really have only those two states? Maybe one is `:out_of_service` for instance?

Again, no idea. The question doesn't say.

Or it could be that available/busy can be - and likely *should* be - inferred from something else. There's no reason to manually track multiple separate state values if they're dependent on each other. In fact, it's likely harmful to try. So perhaps your code could do this instead:

```
def status
  @passengers.any? ? :busy : :available
end
```

Now status is derived from something (presumably) more meaningful.

But does this make sense? No idea. The question doesn't say.

As mentioned, just having `switch_state` is odd because presumably there's more to it than that: The state is connected to something. Otherwise, as I also mentioned, you could replace the whole class with a simple boolean value. Only being able to manipulate the state by flipping it seems weird. Like a light switch you can only even flip to the opposite of whatever it is - and you don't know whether that's on or off.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain why it's not a good question. I learned a lot from your answer! The boolean now makes the most sense. You also explained why it's not a great questions I will take all of your suggestions into consideration before adding new questions. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

This takes the `Taxi` class in a different direction a little bit, but I think a `switch_status` method is not what you want. The status of a Taxi is a reflection of its current state. Code outside the Taxi class should not be allowed to switch the status.

- A taxi is available if it has no passengers
- A taxi is "busy" if it is currently on a trip

Seems like you need a `begin_trip` method that accepts a destination and any number of passengers, and a `complete_trip` method that returns the array of passenger objects and makes the taxi available again.

```
class Taxi
  def initialize
    @status = :available
  end

  def available?
    @status == :available
  end

  def begin_trip(destination, *passengers)
    raise 'Cannot accept passengers at this time' unless @passengers.nil?
    @passengers = passengers
    @status = :busy
  end

  def complete_trip
    passengers = @passengers
    @passengers = nil
    @status = :available

    passengers
  end
end
```

The taxi's availability is a reflection of how the object is currently being used:

```
taxi = Taxi.new
taxi.available? # => true
taxi.begin_trip 'The Grand Canyon', 'Bill', 'Janet'
taxi.available? # => false
passengers = taxi.complete_trip
taxi.available? # => true
```